# ASP.NET with VS 2008 How to Run Root "/" with Local Web Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to use the built-in web server for VS 2008 and have it run my web-site project as the top level root "/". Instructions for VS 2005 can be found at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/19/tip-trick-how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-local-web-server-using-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

My problem is with step 3 of the instructions. When the the web-site project node is selected, right click never gives me an option to select a property-grid like that shown under step 3. Nor could I find another way in the menu or tool bar to get the property-grid.

I don't know if the UI difference I'm seeing has to do with me using VS 2008 and the instructions are for VS 2005 or what?

How do I get the web-site property-grid for VS 2008, or is there an alternative way to get the root setup I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the website, and then press "F4" to bring up the Properties interface.  You should see the Virtual Path there.

Comment: Duh! Obviously the instructions were referring to the standard VS property window. I kept thinking they were referring to a pop-up property window some MS applications have via right click. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: VS2008 does actually have a property pages popup for websites, but it doesnt contain the property you need